# Websocket - Https

Tags: node.js, websocket, https, socket.io

I modified my socketio to receive via https, the first service worked normally but one of the services stopped working. Follow the socketio.conf confs. Is there any configuration that needs to be done in Apache?

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
    TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
    LogLevel warn
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLCipherSuite HIGH:3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!SEED:!IDEA
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/serve.serve.com.b/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile  /etc/letsencrypt/live/serve.serve.com.br/privkey.pem

    <Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Files>
    <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
             nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
             downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \
              "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} ^Upgrade$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/socket.io            [NC]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket    [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*)           wss://127.0.0.1:4540/$1 [P,L]
    ProxyPass        /socket.io https://127.0.0.1:4540/socket.io
    ProxyPassReverse /socket.io https://127.0.0.1:4540/socket.io
</VirtualHost>
```

successful websocket connection.